# Finding an Textfile Ezine to Write For

Tags: writing-groups

I am an eighth grader who is about halfway through reading all of the "Hogs of Entropy" issues.  Reading through them, I realized that formality is not the focus of the pieces, which intrigues me to write similar pieces.  However, I cannot seem to find a group similar to HOE to write for...  Does anybody know a group similar to HOE??  If not, any ideas on where to go next?

Comment: http://www.textfiles.com/magazines/

Comment: This question is either vague and incomplete or I am not American enough to get it.

Comment: Agreed, this is a question that's not answerable within out Q&A format. CodeAdmiral, please read our FAQ for more information about asking questions here. In particular, they need to be questions that can be answered definitively, and not with a list of answers that are potentially all equally as valid.